# how to proof that φ:P(N)→2N φ(A)=f where f(n)=1 if and only if n∈A is bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

so i have given the folowing info:

In general, if $A$ is a set, for $S \in \mathcal P(A)$ define $\chi(S) : A \to \{0,1\}$ by $$\chi(S)(a) = \begin{cases} 1 & \textrm{if } a \in S, \\ 0 & \textrm{if } a \notin S. \end{cases}$$
Then $\chi : \mathcal P(A) \to 2^A$ is bijective.

But I was wondering how I can prove this. I know you suppose to show that the function χ(S)(a) is both injective as surjective. But I'm pretty new with the definition Characteristic function so I don't know how to start.

I know my definitions:

injective:
a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is injective when:

$\forall x_1,x_2 \in X: x_1 \ne x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$

$\forall x_1,x_2 \in X: f(x_1) = f(x_2) \Rightarrow x_1 = x_2 $

surjective:
a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective when:

$\forall y \in Y : \exists x \in X: f(x)=y$

but how can I apply it in my case?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you can find a (two-sided) inverse function to $\chi$, then that will prove bijectivity without explicitly checking injectivity and surjectivity. It's not too difficult to imagine what the inverse is.

Comment: Thank you so much for your respond, you made my day :)